# RTSP library for Java

Tags: java, rtsp

I'm looking for a RTSP Java library, but I didn't find anything.
Can someone advice me a Java library to handle RTSP?

Thanks

Comment: Use Gstreamer View my answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039801/rtsp-streaming-on-java/7475559#7475559

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you still need that. I wrote a tiny RTSP Client library in java and I'd appreciate some feedback on it. Also, it can be extended to implement server side.

The link to the project is http://code.google.com/p/rtsplib-java/

Regards, Paulo.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one in C# if you wanna port something http://net7mma.codeplex.com/